# Connection lost issue

Tags: plugins

I am getting following message in WordPress Admin Panel

**Connection lost. Saving has been disabled until you’re reconnected.   We’re backing up this post in your browser, just in case.**

What can be the problem??

Thanks

Comment: Is this a self hosted install? Or is it on Wordpress.com or some other service?

Comment: I am getting this error in my localhost.

Comment: what is the version of php,mysql and apache you are using?